# Error converting client characters into server’s?

Tags: coldfusion, special-characters, sybase

I have textarea field where user copy/paste the text from word document. When user tried to save the form this error message was returned fromt he server:

`Error converting characters into server's character set. Some character(s) could not be converted.`

After looking carefully over the text that user entered in the field I found out which character is causing the issue. So when user copy/paste the text from the word document dash character is different/longer than standard dash. So the text looks like this:

`Red – All devices muted/Do not disturb is enabled`

I simply replaced the dash and text looked like this:

`Red - All devices muted/Do not disturb is enabled`

and I was able to save the form. I'm wondering what I can do to correct/prevent this kind of issues? I use `ColdFusion 2018` on the back end in combination with `Sybase` database. If anyone have suggestions on how to fix this error please let me know.

Comment: Wow. There a lot 'dashes' in Unicode. Looks like 24 of them: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Pd

Comment: Any recommendations on how to solve this issue?

Comment: @espresso_coffee what line of code is returning that error?

Comment: @DanRoberts I listed an error message in my questions. It's related to dash `-` in the text.

Comment: @espresso_coffee my question was to help determine what exactly is generating the error. You will need to narrow that down. Does any hit to the server that passes that dash cause the error, only passing it to a CF page, only passing the value to a specific function, only inserting the dash into the database, etc? Usually such an error would be related to a specific line of code so figuring that out would be a good place to start. Do you have any environment for debugging?

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?)?  if ASE ... the dataserver is configured with a default character set (ie, *ALL* data is stored in the dataserver under said charset); while ASE can 'support' clients/programs running with different charsets, this 'support' comes in the form of converting data between charsets (for writes ASE converts client/program charset into ASE charset; for reads ASE converts ASE charset to client/program charset); if some characters cannot be converted between the charsets then you get the warning message ...

Comment: I say 'warning message' because you should find the data was inserted into ASE but some characters were not properly converted; if you find the row does not exist in the database then I'm guessing the client/program (ColdFusion?) may be rolling back the insert due to the warning message; to eliminate the warning message the client/program will either need to scrub the data of incompatible characters or the DBA will need to reconfigure ASE to use a charset that can handle the desired charset conversions (eg, config ASE to use utf8)